# First Eclipse Android app, showing blank screen

Tags: java, android, adt, eclipse-adt

So, this is my first android application. I am using Eclipse Kepler, I've installed the ADT and also the SDK is setup. Even with the example that comes with a new android application from eclipse, when I hit run, it's starting the emulator, but I just get a blank screen in it.

I've tried different Devices, and I can choose only one target for the virtual device manager: **Android 4.4 - API Level 19**

**What settings I've used:**

Application name: myfirstapp

Project name: myfirstapp

Package com.example.myfirstapp

**For the rest of the settings, I've let them default:**

Minimum Required SDK: API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo)

Target SDK: API 18

Compile With: API 19: Android 4.4 (KitKat)

Theme: (default)

I've also tried to set all the above settings to API 19: Android 4.4 (KitKat), but nothing changes.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: What _should_ be displayed instead?

Comment: Actually, if I create the virtual device with Use Host GPU, I get "android" showing. Updated the post with an image

Comment: So, is this an emulator problem or an app problem?

Comment: I don't know, it's just my first app

Comment: can you create AVD with target sdk.

Comment: this is emulator problem.

Comment: I can select only 1 target sdk: Android 4.4 - API Level 19

Comment: create an emulator that is running API 18 or 19

Comment: The screenshot shows emulator is starting...

Try to start emulator by choosing device in AVD Manager().         After starting of emulator ,right click on your application name (in Application explorer) and click on run as->Android application.

Comment: I've start the virtual device "manually", it looks like it took a while to start it up, I see an android mobile interface, but my application is not in it. I'll try again, and wait a bit longer for it to start.

Comment: will you post your Manifest file of application?

Comment: I think it's just taking a while.

Comment: Yep, it's taking some time. Works now.

Answer (score 1):

Your android emulator is loading, you only have to wait.